# Classify all invertible meromorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, self-learning

I am studying complex analysis. And I see a topic, namely *meremorphic functions*

But I cannot find any enough information about this function. So I have insufficient knowledge about this topic.

And I have found a question like following below with its answer.

Please can someone explain the answer of this question in more detail explanatorily? I Will be happy. Thank you so much for helping:)

---

**Question:** classify all invertible meromorphic functions from $\Bbb C\cup \{\infty\}$ to $\Bbb C \cup \{\infty\}$

---

**The question with its answer:**

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for somebody to explain the question, or its answer? Do you own any books on complex analysis? Is there a set of notes you are working out of?

Comment: Yes, there exist this topic in the textbook, but it is explained too superficially:( so i dont understand. And I want explain its answer. Thank you @BrettFrankel

Comment: What part of the solution don't you understand?

Comment: As I said that above, in general Dear @Potato

Comment: @B11b What specific statements or claims? If there are many of them, why not pick out a few specific ones to start with? It is much easier to answer specific questions than to re-explain a whole proof.

Comment: @B11b From which book (or lecture notes) is the screenshot above taken from? I would be interested in knowing! :)